# javascript window.open() to a html file opens the browser download dialog

Tags: javascript

I'm creating a print (preview)window, for which I want to load the core html from the site assets:

The code:

```
window.open('/SiteAssets/reportingPrintBase.html','_blank','width=1250,height=800,menubar=yes,scrollbars=yes,resizable=yes');
```

The html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" lang="en-us" dir="ltr">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<meta http-equiv="Expires" content="0" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/SiteAssets/reporting.css" />
<title>Untitled 1</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="printHeader">Reporting</div>
<div id="printBody"></div>
<div id="printFooter">Reporting Footer</div>
</body>
</html>
```

The popup opens, but I'm then asked if want to download the file. This doesn't happen in a normal asp.net env. So I'm assuming it has something to do whith the way sharepoint sets headers..

So how can I get the popup window to simply render the html?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you could use the default sharepoint popup-method?

```
<a href="javascript:SP.UI.ModalDialog.OpenPopUpPage('/SiteAssets/reportingPrintBase.html');">Do something</a>
```

You can set these parameters:

```
SP.UI.ModalDialog.OpenPopUpPage(url, callback, width, height);
```

With:

- url: The URL of the page to be shown in the modal dialog.
- callback: The callback function that runs when the modal dialog is closed.
- width: The width of the modal dialog.
- height: The height of the modal dialog.

Answer (score 0):

Is the html set up correctly in IIS? Looks like a mime/ content-type related thingie..
If not.. Have you tried another Browser?